# JavaFx Gui Exception in Application start method

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I have basically only a not coded Gui, and still got that exception  although had some working guis before with a little code. so what confuses most.. There's basically only a gui and there isnt much code to delete, fix.. so why this gui isn't showing up? p.s. fxml is in the right directory, for sure

**MAIN**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        AnchorPane pane =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Gui.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();


}
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
DropShadow ds = new DropShadow();
@FXML
ButtonGroup group;
@FXML
RadioButton radio1;
@FXML
RadioButton radio2;
@FXML
RadioButton radio3;
@FXML
Label changelog;
@FXML
TextArea changelogarea;
@FXML
Pane panechange;
@FXML
AnchorPane mainanchor;

Controller(){
changelog.setEffect(ds);    
}







@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**FXML**

```
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="mainanchor" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="panechange" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="-3.0" prefHeight="406.0" prefWidth="493.0">
     <children>
        <Label fx:id="changelog" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="21.0" prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="463.0" text="                     Change log" textAlignment="CENTER">
           <font>
              <Font size="27.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <TextArea fx:id="changelogarea" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="329.0" prefWidth="487.0" />
     </children>
  </Pane>
  <RadioButton fx:id="radio2" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Valiuta">
     <toggleGroup>
        <ToggleGroup fx:id="group" />
     </toggleGroup>
  </RadioButton>
  <RadioButton fx:id="radio3" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="94.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Atstumai" toggleGroup="$group" />
  <RadioButton fx:id="radio1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="32.0" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Naujienos" toggleGroup="$group" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**error**

> Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62
>   )     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
>   .java:43)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherIm
>   pl.java:363)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:
>   303)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62
>   )     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
>   .java:43)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java
>   :875)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Launche
>   rImpl.java:157)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/128893786.run(Unknown
>   Sou rce)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
>   /E:/Programming/Java/WorkSpace/FxConverter/bin/application/Gui.fxml:11
>
> at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:930)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoade
>   r.java:967)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2701)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2521)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3208)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)     at
>   application.Main.start(Main.java:21)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Launch
>   erImpl.java:821)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1596489439.run(Unknown
>   So urce)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.j
>   ava:323)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1051754451.run(Unknown
>   So urce)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:29
>   2)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1001120425.run(Unknown
>   So urce)  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.jav
>   a:291)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1775282465.run(Unknown
>   So urce)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java
>   :95)  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown
>   Source )  ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
>   Class sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil  can not access a member of class
>   application.Controller with modifiers ""  at
>   sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:101)    at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:432)   at
>   sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:923)
>     ... 27 more Exception running application application.Main

Comment: Besides the errors shown in @eckig's answer, you have one other error I can see: in the controller you define `group` as a `ButtonGroup` (not sure what that is, you didn't show your imports); it should be a `ToggleGroup` as that's how it's defined in the FXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. The constructor of your controller has to be public. See this thread for reference: [JavaFX IllegalAccessException during FXML load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504300/javafx-illegalaccessexception-during-fxml-load)
2. The controller constructor will not work, since you are trying to access a field which is not available at that point.

So for 2. move `changelog.setEffect(ds);` from the controller to the `initialize` method.

Comment: deleted everything about ds effect, this line from constructor and "DropShadow ds = new DropShadow();" still same error, so i think this isnt the problem. but thanks for the tip for the future.

Comment: @RaXenel What error do you get? Any stacktrace for us?

Comment: added an error, worked perfectly until added few more components to the gui.

Comment: still same, constructor is empty so i think it has no bi g impact on this

Comment: You get the exact same error message with a `public` constructor? That seems pretty unlikely...

Comment: yep, public constructor havent solved any errors, but using initialize and that toggleGroup did, thanks everyone, this havent only solved errors, but also tought me few additional things.

Comment: It's actually impossible to get the error you posted if the constructor is public, but I'm glad you figured it out anyway.